# Using ES6 and typescript in nodejs command line application

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, command, line

I am looking to develop a nodejs application using typescript and was wondering if it is possible to do so.
I tried just installing typescript but I get an error when I try to export by default / import from :

```
(node:1696) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
import test from "./test";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1054:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1102:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

i also tried with < ES6 notation (module.exports and require) but it seems that typescript is not supported with this notation...

i'm starting my application using `npm link` and `yyyyyy` with the following package.json :

```
{
  "name": "yyyyyy",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "tslint -c tslint.json -p tsconfig.json"
  },
  "bin": {
    "yyyyyy": "./bin/index.ts"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/xxx"
  },
  "author": "xxx",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/xxx"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/xxx",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^17.0.18",
    "tslint": "^5.12.1",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To enable ES6 you need to add

`'type': 'module`

Inside package.json. ones do that you can use import, otherwise you need to use require.

For more info check it [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v13.x/api/esm.html#esm_enabling)

UPDATE:

Based on your comment, if you want to use import then you need to add in your tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  }
}
```

Then you can install:

`npm install -g ts-node`

After this you can run:

`ts-node my_server.ts`

If not work yet you can update your tsconfig.json change

`module: "es6"`

To

`module: "commonjs"`

And removing:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  }
}
```

Comment: I also tried. sorry, i forgot to mention that. It gives me an error : ```(node:15136) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
internal/modules/run_main.js:54
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for ...```.
I'm checking your source :)

Comment: I think i'm not using nodejs as o should. I am only doing npm link and then [bin_name] <options>, i'm not running a server (ex: express). Im still getting unknown file extension ".ts" for .../bin/index.ts